# React router. Hacer que el proyecto abra por defecto en una ruta determinada

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Cómo hacer que el proyecto abra (al darle npm start) por defecto en una ruta determinada. Ej:  http://localhost:3000/home

```
  <Router>
        <ul>
          <li> <Link to="/home">Home</Link> </li>
        </ul>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/:id?"  render={(props) => <SearchResults/>} />
      </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu código dónde gestionas las rutas??

Comment: Lo añadí a la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el componente "Redirect" de la librearía react-router, a su vez también puedes utilizar un "DefaultRoute".
En este ejemplo utilizaremos el componente "Redirect", se requiere que lo utilices en tu componente de Routes:

```
<Switch>
  <Redirect from="/" exact to="/home" />
  <Route path="/:id?"  render={(props) => <SearchResults/>} />
</Switch>
```